# How to configure git line endings simple and minimal?

Tags: git, line-endings, gitattributes

my assumption is that only in batch files windows line endings should be allowed. Everywhere else should be used the git internal mechanic to recognize binary files and all other text files should enforce linux file endings. Can this be configured simple, i.e. without `.gitattributes` and listing all kind of file types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can this be configured without .gitattributes?

No, it has to be configured *somewhere*, and .gitattributes is the appropriate somewhere.

> Can this be configured without listing all kind of file types?

Yes, you can use a pattern match of `*` to match all files, and the special attribute `text=auto`. Quoting [the manual page for gitattributes](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes):

> When `text` is set to "auto", the path is marked for automatic end-of-line conversion. If Git decides that the content is text, its line endings are converted to LF on checkin. When the file has been committed with CRLF, no conversion is done.

Note also the order of precedence:

> When more than one pattern matches the path, a later line overrides an earlier line. This overriding is done per attribute.

So all you need are two rules:

```
# Unless over-ridden, detect text files automatically, and use Unix line endings
*      text=auto eol=lf

# Over-ride batch files to always be text, and use Windows line endings
*.bat  text      eol=crlf
```

Comment: Looks very good, but as I checked out before this file already the current working copy is not updated to LF, even if I do `git add --renormalize .`. Why is that? Is that only after checkin?